# In Bode plots what does phase tell us for passive filters (open loop)?

Tags: capacitor, filter, bode-plot, emi-filtering, passive-filter

I was just playing around with a passive filter to erase some noise - one that should work between 80MHz and 1GHz.

I'm aware that the phase in Bode plots gives data about the time delay between the input and the output. Knowing this, if a \$\sin(xt)\$ signal is applied at a frequency where phase is -180º then the signal will be completely inverted.

For closed loops systems / active op amp filters this is a no go, since the system will go unstable. **Is there any setback for passive systems and open loops?**

**I don't know what to find in the phase plot when designing passive filters.**

This is my plot. Phase is dotted green.

(I know in the range of GHz parasitic inductance/capacitance have effects, and the resonance of Cs Ls too, so the plot won't be like that. But below that and around 1GHz it should be close.)

[image]

This is the filter, with parasitic values added:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *But there is any setback for passive systems and open loops ?*

No, there are no particular drawbacks that can cause instability. Instability may only happen when there is an active gain device and feedback is involved. You can, by cascading many passive filters, produce phase shifts much more than 360° quite easily.

Having said that, if you are expecting your filter to remove noise from a complex shaped signal without affecting the general shape of the wanted signal, you can easily be disappointed with the result but, it won't be unstable.

> *I don't know what to see/find in the phase plot when designing passive
> filters.*

That would require the content of whole books to explain.

<sub>By the way, your bode plot is cut-off at the top so, it's impossible to know what node it connects to</sub>

Comment: Ok thanks Andy. My signal is pretty simple, just a analog output of a ratiometric hall sensor. So no fancy shapes. The node its CRC-LC-damped, image updated.